# Student sees all courses on the main page

Tags: moodle

I have problem with LMS Moodle: students see all courses on the main page, but I want, that they see only courses, where they are enrolled.

Is it possible to configure Moodle in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change the settings for the front page

```
/admin/settings.php?section=frontpagesettings
```

Change "Front page items when logged in" to "Enrolled courses"

and remove "Front page" "List of courses"

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I think that the option is only available since Moodle 2.5.

Comment: Ah, which version of Moodle are you using?